# Routing in Kohana in development

Tags: php, routes, kohana, mamp

I am setting up my new web application using the Kohana framework.

I am using MAMP so the app is located in the `htdocs` folder, with this structure:

```
---htdocs
 --foo
  -application
```

I am getting this error when viewing `http://localhost:8888/foo/`

```
Kohana_HTTP_Exception[ 404 ]: The requested URL foo was not found on this server.
```

In the `bootstrap.php` the route is the default Kohana one

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')->defaults(
array(
    'controller' => 'welcome',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

Comment: Have you set the `base_url` in the bootstrap.php (and the `RewriteBase` in your .htaccess) properly?

Comment: Can you advise me what these should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `application/bootstrap.php` file for:

```
Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url'   => '/foo/',
));
```

This is required for Kohana to understand it's in `/foo/` folder.

**UPD**
`The requested URL foo was not found on this server` exception message is generated if no `action_<action>` method was found in Controller.

If no Route was found `Unable to find a route to match the URI:` exception message is genereted.

Not shure Routing works as expected, but it works ;).

So check your Controller file for apropriate action method.

Answer (score 0):

This is would be my prefered folder structure for a Kohana application under `/foo`:

```
├─┬─ htdocs
│ └─┬─ foo
│   ├─── .htaccess
│   └─── index.php
└─┬─ kohana
  ├─┬─ application
  │ ├─── bootstrap.php
  │ └─── etc...
  ├─┬─ modules
  │ └─── etc...
  ├─┬─ system
  │ └─── etc...
  ├─── index.php
  ├─── install.php
  └─── etc...
```

htdocs/foo/index.php:

```
<?php

require '../../kohana/index.php';
```

htdocs/foo/.htaccess:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /foo/

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

In kohana/application/bootsrap.php set 'base_url' to foo:

```
Kohana::init(array(
        'base_url' => '/foo/',
        'index_file' => NULL,
));
```

If you want to run kohana/install.php create htdocs/foo/install.php and require '../../kohana/install.php';

This way you keep your htdocs clean. If your live server would ever stop processing PHP files for some reason the only thing people will get to see is a require to Kohana's `index.php`.

The RewriteCond for the `application`, `modules` and `system` folders is not needed.

Turning on maintenance mode is very easy.

Comment: Shouldn't `application` dir be inside `foo` as well? Files inside shouldn't be shared with other systems using same kohana, should they?

Comment: No. If you only have one Kohana application, then this works fine. If you have more then one running the same version you could move `kohana/application/` to `applications/foo`. You do not want `application/` (or however you named it) under the webroot if you can avoid it.